# "unrecognized selector sent to class" when calling category method from a library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, extension-methods, foundation, unrecognized-selector

## Problem

This question may seem a bit long, but I try to give as much information as possible, since I am really staggered by this.

I am currently working an a [library](https://github.com/hverr/CeasyXML) which should automate XML document parsing. But I am running into a problem now testing the library for the first time.

I have a library class called `CSXDocumentLayout` which represents the layout of a document. This class contains the private method `- (NSError *)readLayoutDocument:(NSString *)fpath` called from an init method.

```
/* MARK: Reading in Layouts */
- (NSError *)readLayoutDocument:(NSString *)fpath {
    CSXDocumentLayout *layout;
    CSXXMLParser *parser;
    BOOL state;

    layout = [CSXDocumentLayout layoutDocumentLayout];

    parser = [[CSXXMLParser alloc] initWithDocumentLayouts:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:layout]];
    parser.file = fpath;

    state = [parser parse];

    if(state == NO || parser.error != nil) {
        return parser.error;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This method will read in an XML document representing the layout of an other XML document. It is parsed by the class `CSXXMLParser`, which I want to test.

I create an object representing a layout document with `+[CSXDocumentLayout layoutDocumentLayout]`. This method is implemented in the category `CSXDocumentLayout (CSXLayoutObject)`.

Below is my test file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CeasyXML.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    NSString *file;

    file = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__];
    file = [file stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    file = [file stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Layout.xml"];

    CSXDocumentLayout *layout;
    NSError *error;

    layout = [[CSXDocumentLayout alloc] initWithLayoutDocument:file 
                                                         error:&error];
    if(layout == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Could not create layout: %@", error);
        exit(0);
    }

    NSLog(@"Layout:\n%@", layout);

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

This file compiles to a separate executable linked to my static library *libceasyxml.a*. Everything compiles just fine without any warnings.

But when I run it I get a **unrecognized selector sent to class** exception:

```
2012-05-02 16:59:47.620 TestApp[1887:a0f] +[CSXDocumentLayout layoutDocumentLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000064c8
2012-05-02 16:59:47.791 TestApp[1887:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[CSXDocumentLayout layoutDocumentLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000064c8'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83e47784 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff84604f03 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83ea11a0 __CFFullMethodName + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83e198ef ___forwarding___ + 751
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83e15a38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   TestApp                             0x0000000100001512 -[CSXDocumentLayout(Private) readLayoutDocument:] + 49
    6   TestApp                             0x00000001000010d4 -[CSXDocumentLayout initWithLayoutDocument:error:] + 96
    7   TestApp                             0x0000000100001017 main + 179
    8   TestApp                             0x0000000100000f5c start + 52
    9   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

I find it very disturbing that I cannot call the class method `+[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) layoutDocumentLayout]`, though I can call both `-[CSXDocumentLayout initWithLayoutDocument:error:]`, and `-[CSXDocumentLayout(Private) readLayoutDocument:]`.

## Research

I checked if the method is defined in the output files by running `nm file` and it is, well partly:

**In libceasyxml.a, it is defined *(nm libceasyxml.a)***

```
...
libceasyxml.a(CSXDocumentLayout+CSXLayoutObject.o):
0000000000000100 t +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) classAttributeLayout]
00000000000020e0 s +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) classAttributeLayout].eh
000000000000056b t +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) documentElementLayout]
0000000000002180 s +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) documentElementLayout].eh
0000000000000402 t +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) layoutDocumentLayout]
0000000000002148 s +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) layoutDocumentLayout].eh
0000000000000200 t +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) layoutElementLayout]
0000000000002110 s +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) layoutElementLayout].eh
0000000000000000 t +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) nameAttributeLayout]
00000000000020b0 s +[CSXDocumentLayout(CSXLayoutObject) nameAttributeLayout].eh
0000000000002098 s EH_frame1
0000000000001c49 s LC0
...
```

**In TestApp, it is NOT defined *(nm TestApp)***, actually I can't find any method with the category name `CSXLayoutObject`.

```
...
0000000100001271 t -[CSXDocumentLayout setDocumentClassString:]
00000001000013a8 t -[CSXDocumentLayout setElements:]
0000000100001490 t -[CSXDocumentLayout setName:]
00000001000014db t -[CSXDocumentLayout(Private) readLayoutDocument:]
0000000100004060 t -[CSXElementList dealloc]
00000001000040b0 t -[CSXElementList elements]
...
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed broken link

I suspect you have run into a known problem of [categories embedded in static libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1490/_index.html).

If I am right, try to compile with the linker flags `-ObjC` (and if that is not enough, also `-all_load`) and your problem should disappear.

Comment: For future readers, I had to add the flag to 'other linking flags' under the 'linking' menu. (ios 6.1, xcode 4.3)

Comment: While this answer is often the solution, the other one, provided by Ace, is a great complimentary one, and covers another possible case.

Comment: The link is broken now, is there an archive of it?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the answer is already selected, I wish the solution to my issue was here, as simple as it may be. Be sure to check that your class is properly checked in the `Target Membership` field under the `File Inspector` pane. If you fail to do so then it's only natural to receive the `unrecognized selector sent to class` error.

Comment: That was it for me! Thank you kind stranger!